# TinyMCE not loaded in vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tinymce

I'm trying to integrate tinymce in my vue app. I don't want to use the cloud version and I've installed it inside my app suing this commend `npm i tinymce`.

After the setup into my component I've imported the needed files in this way and I created a textarea into the template

```html
<template>
    <Navbar></Navbar>
    <div class="container" id="editorWrapper">
        <div class="row mt-5 pt-5 m-0">
            <!--  -->
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 p-0" id="">
                <h1>Write post</h1>
            </div>
            <!--  -->
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 p-0" id="programEditorWrapper">
                <textarea ref="programEditor" id="programEditor"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
import tinymce from 'tinymce'
import 'tinymce/themes/silver'
import 'tinymce/skins/ui/oxide/skin.css'
import 'tinymce/plugins/advlist'
import 'tinymce/plugins/code'
import 'tinymce/plugins/emoticons'
import 'tinymce/plugins/emoticons/js/emojis'
import 'tinymce/plugins/link'
import 'tinymce/plugins/lists'
import 'tinymce/plugins/table'
import contentUiCss from 'tinymce/skins/ui/oxide/content.css'
import contentCss from 'tinymce/skins/content/default/content.css'


export default {
    name: 'ProgramsEditor',
    components: {
        Navbar
    },
    data() {
        return {
            editor: null
        }
    },
    created() {

    },
    mounted() {
        this.initEditor()
    },
    methods: {
        initEditor() {
            this.editor = tinymce.init({
                selector: '#programEditor',
                plugins: 'advlist code emoticons link lists table',
                toolbar: 'bold italic | bullist numlist | link emoticons',
                skin: false,
                content_css: false,
                content_style: contentUiCss.toString() + '\n' + contentCss.toString()
            })
        }, 
    }
}
</script>
```

Unfortunately I'm not able to see the editor and I get two errors
[image]

How I can fix this problem and let the editor work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the error message and the code snippet provided, you've missed importing some critical files that TinyMCE uses, as such its trying to load the external JS files which don't appear to exist or are being served as HTML files (potentially a 404 page).

I'd suggest reviewing the TinyMCE bundling docs further, which hold the answer here: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/introduction-to-bundling-tinymce/. So in this case, to solve the 2 errors you're getting that should be able to be resolved by importing the model and default icon pack alongside the theme:

```js
import tinymce from 'tinymce'
import 'tinymce/icons/default';
import 'tinymce/themes/silver';
import 'tinymce/models/dom';
```

Basically, TinyMCE at the very minimum needs the core, theme, skin, default icon pack and model to be able to operate (Note: the model is new in TinyMCE 6 and wasn't needed before that). If any of those are missed then it will fail to initialize.

Comment: I will give a try. At the moment to prototype my app component I've switched to CKEditor and seems working fine. I will test later also with tinyMCE by importing the needed files. I was missed something in my import. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Additionally, you could use the [official Vue integration guide](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/vue/).

After installation.
Simple input the core packages:
**You need both the core tinymce package and tinymce-vue installed.**

```
import "tinymce/tinymce";
import "tinymce/themes/silver";
import "tinymce/icons/default";
import "tinymce/skins/ui/oxide/skin.css";
import <Your component name here> from "@tinymce/tinymce-vue";
```

And use it as a normal Vue component.

Comment: Worth noting this example doesn't take into account the `model` that's erroring in the attached screenshot so you'd also need the `import 'tinymce/models/dom';` line for TinyMCE 6+. While using the official vue wrapper will help with some things and I'd also recommend it, it doesn't solve the bundling issues which appear to be the core issue in the original post.

Comment: @newso so the problem is related to the required import needed to let tinyMCE works correctly inside vue right?

Comment: Yeah, that's correct or at least that's what your screenshot shows.